# How much electric energy can be produced by a given size of piezo material?

Tags: piezoelectric

Piezoelectric materials produce electric charges when deformed. For a given size of a piezoelectric material, say quartz, how much total electric energy can be produced ?

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

Increase the deforming force from zero up to the limit at which any further force would break the crystal. The amount of mechanical work done in this process will necessarily be an **upper bound** on the amount of electrical energy produced.